# How to hide the data behind the popup which appears on mouse hover?

Tags: html, css, popup

Here is my css.

```
#driver_list{
    overflow:hidden;
    }
div#driver_price_pop_up{
      position: absolute;
      width: 20%;
      min-height:200px;
      background:white;
      color: red;
      border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
}
.head_popup_price{

    width:100%;
    min-height:50px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-size:16px;
}

.popup_body_price{
    width:100%;
    min-height:150px;
    color:black;
    background:#e6ffff;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

The driver_list tag is like the container tag , the #driver_price_pop_up id contains a popup which comes up when a user mouse hover a particular things and goes away when on mouse-move.The head_popup_price is the class assigned to the head of the popup ,popup_body_price is a class assigned to body of the popup.The problem is when the popup comes , the data behind that is also visible. the data should not be visible.I tried giving `overflow:hidden` to the driver_list but it's not working.
guys please help me.
my html code.

```
<div id="driver_price_pop_up" >

                <div class="head_popup_price">Head</div>
                <div class="popup_body_price">Pop-up div Successfully Displayed</div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle.

Comment: please put the html code

Comment: @haithamsha included the html code.

Comment: Try adding a z-index to your pop-up.

Comment: i gave that...not helping..@Legin76

Comment: Are you sure that #driver_price_pop_up is not showing up behind the content? If so #driver_price_pop_up {z-index:10} should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Actually You are near to your result

```
<div class="driver_price_pop_up">
<div class="head_popup_price">Head</div>
<div class="popup_body_price">Pop-up div Successfully Displayed</div>
</div>
<style>
.head_popup_price{ 
display: none;
}
.driver_price_pop_up:hover .head_popup_price{
display : block;
}
.driver_price_pop_up:hover .popup_body_price{
display : none;
}
.popup_body_price{
width:100%;
min-height:150px;
color:black;
background:#e6ffff;
border:1px solid black;
font-size:18px;
}
.head_popup_price{
width:100%;
min-height:50px;
background:black;
color:white;
border:1px solid black;
font-size:16px;
}
.driver_price_pop_up{
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  min-height:200px;
  background:white;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  }
</style>
```

This is example to hover to show one div content. Try it

Answer (score 0):

try this work for me but i did hover by jquery(javascript library make life easy)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="Content/main2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("div").hover(
        function () {
            // display pop up div
         $('#driver_price_pop_up').show();
         },
        function () {
            // hide pop up div
          $('#driver_price_pop_up').hide();
         }
         );
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="driver_price_pop_up">
    <div class="head_popup_price">Head</div>
    <div class="popup_body_price">Pop-up div Successfully Displayed</div>
</div>
<div class="mydiv">
    content shoud be pop up appear on it
</div>
</body>
```

css

```
#driver_list{
overflow:hidden;
}
div#driver_price_pop_up{
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  min-height:200px;
  background:white;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  display:none;
  margin:30px;
}
.head_popup_price{

width:100%;
min-height:50px;
background:black;
color:white;
border:1px solid black;
font-size:16px;
}

.popup_body_price{
width:100%;
min-height:150px;
color:black;
background:#e6ffff;
border:1px solid black;
font-size:18px;
}
```

Comment: javascript is working fine. The problem is the css , the background thing is not going.

Comment: see there is a datatable behind it. the content of the datatable is  visible.
when the popup come up,  the content of the datatable is still visible in the popup. the datat of the popup and the data of the datatable are overlapping.

Comment: I'm add 2 property to the div#driver_price_pop_up, display:none;
      margin:30px; just please try my example it work fine for me